# Having problems using google cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions

```
message: "Build failed: *** Error compiling './main.py'...
  File "./main.py", line 85
    "prompt": prompt, 
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax; Error ID: 49c34848"
```

```py
if user_request == "longer responses":
    model_config = {
        "engine": "gpt3",
        "model": ["text-davinci-002", "text-davinci-003", "text-curie-001", "text-babbage-001", "text-ada-001",]
        "prompt": prompt, 
        "temperature": 0.9,  # set the temperature to a high value
        "max_tokens": 300,  # set the max_tokens filter to 160 tokens
```

It doesnt work. I tried add ing semicolons. It doesnt work

Comment: The comma on the `model` line needs to be outside the `]`. So instead of `..."text-ada-001",]`, you should use `..."text-ada-001"],`

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is incorrect, it remains `}` character to write correctly the `Python` `Dict`. I also removed a useless coma in the array :

```py
if user_request == "longer responses":
    model_config = {
        "engine": "gpt3",
        "model": ["text-davinci-002", "text-davinci-003", "text-curie-001", "text-babbage-001", "text-ada-001"]
        "prompt": prompt, 
        "temperature": 0.9,  # set the temperature to a high value
        "max_tokens": 300  # set the max_tokens filter to 160 tokens
   }
```